# StandAlone GUI in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I was looking at the offerings of the Java platform for developing a stand alone application. However, I am stuck at making a decision for the presentation layer between Java FX and Swing? Are they being actively supported? I am open to look into any other framework as well? Please suggest.

Comment: The decision is opinion based. Please look i to this stuff using google

Comment: Swing will be replaced by JavaFX in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on a new project from scratch, I would highly recommend jumping right to *JavaFX*, which is considered as the successor of the *Swing* technology.

*JavaFX*, henceforth, is the official GUI toolkit upon release of the 8th version of Oracle JDK, and AFAIK, the *Swing* package is no more under development and currently supported with bug fixes only.

In addition, *JavaFX* is more and more spread within Java developers and is gaining a wide support from the community; thanks to its set of advanced features:

- Swing interoperability.
- Canvas API.
- Rich Text Support.
- Built in control and support of CSS styling
- and a lot more and more...